# Provide Starting Positions to t-distributed Stochastic Neighbor Embedding (TSNE) in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I've been looking at using scikit learns' TSNE method to visualize high dimensional data in 2D. However, I have some idea of where the starting positions should be in 2D space but I don't see any way of specifying this information. Any ideas how I might be able to provide the starting coordinates?

I see that there's an "init" parameter but it appears to only take "random" or "pca" as options. What I'm looking for is a way to specify exactly what the initial coordinates are.

**Update**

I'm trying to increase the distance between my data points (~6,500 points) but they are quite tightly clustered and overlapping. With default parameters, I get:

```
model = sklearn.manifold.TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0)
```

[image]

A slight increase in n_iter and early_exaggeration didn't produce significantly different results as the points (within clusters) are still overlapping.

```
model = sklearn.manifold.TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0, n_iter=10000, early_exaggeration=10)
```

[image]

However, increasing the early_exaggeration from 10 to 100 (which, according to the docs, should increase the distance between clusters) produced some unexpected results (I ran this twice and it was the same result):

```
model = sklearn.manifold.TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0, n_iter=10000, early_exaggeration=100)
```

[image]

This link: https://beta.oreilly.com/learning/an-illustrated-introduction-to-the-t-sne-algorithm Provides an example (three quarters of the way down the page) for how to monkey patch the gradient_descent function to save coordinates/positions.

[**Added Issue to scikit-learn**](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4994)

Comment: What do the first to plots look like if you make the points a bit smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is currently not possible, but it would be a two-line change.
I think it would be a good addition, and we do support init=array for things like k-means. So PR welcome.

Comment: I've never done a GH PR before but I will look into what is necessary (suggestions on where to start?). Also, is there a way to save the coordinates at each iteration during the optimization process? I'd like to make a video showing the formation/preservation of structure during the embedding process. Right now, I only see the final visualization.

Comment: Additionally, is there something that I need to do in order to increase the distance/spread of the points in 2D? Currently, I still see a lot of overlap but I'm guessing that I need more iterations (i.e., increase n_iter).

Comment: A guide to contributing is here: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/index.html
Usually the default parameters give pretty good results. Can you post an image of your result?

Comment: It is not possible to keep the progress without hacking the code. It would be possible to get a callback or something similar. Getting that into master would be a major operation, though. Just changing the code for yourself is probably the way to go for that.

Comment: Thanks for the guide. I've updated the post to provide some images and detail of my parameters.

Comment: Added a link for monkey patching the gradient_descent function in the original post.

Comment: I've finally gotten around to trying init=array. However, if I perform one round of tsne with `init='random'` and use the final embedding as input for a second round of tsne (`init=model.embedding_`), I don't get the same embedding back. I expect the embedding to be unchanged since tsne should've converged after the first round and the second round would be like asking tsne for extra iterations. I suspect that it has to do with the two rounds of "early_exaggeration" but it isn't obvious whether there's a way to turn off "early_exaggeration" for the second round of tsne. Any thoughts, Andreas?

Comment: I don't think via the api. Have a look at the code.

Comment: I've looked at and modified the code to accept `early_exaggeration=None` which skips the early_exaggeration step in `_tsne`. However, if I (1) process one round of TSNE using all default values and then (2) use the output from step (1) as input to a second round of TSNE but with early exaggeration turned off (i.e., only perform the `Final optimization`), then the output from the second round is different form the input. I expect the results from step (1) to have converged and that a second TSNE round should (without exaggeration) converge to the same answer since the distances have not changed

Comment: Should I move this thread to the sklearn list? Does one exist? This isn't really a "bug"...

Comment: feel free to got to the issue tracker or the mailing list

Comment: Added new issue to scikit-learn here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4994

Comment: @slaw do you have a link to the code where you were able to turn the off early_exaggeration? I saw your blog post here https://www.oreilly.com/learning/an-illustrated-introduction-to-the-t-sne-algorithm but I only see the _gradient_descent() alteration to register the position of the map points at every iteration